# How to execute stored procedure in SQL Server with output paramter in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I'm getting an error when I try to execute a stored procedure with output parameter in `Sequelize`:

```
Executing (default): spsPerson @PersonID=0 OUTPUT, @Firstname=N'test', @Lastname=N'test'
```

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Cannot use the OUTPUT option when passing a constant to a stored procedure.

This is the code:

```
  seq.query(
    'spsPerson @PersonID=:PersonID OUTPUT, @Firstname=:firstname, @Lastname=:lastname,
    {
      type: seq.QueryTypes.SELECT,
      replacements: {
        PersonID: 0,
        Firstname: 'test',
        Lastname: 'test'
      },
    }
  );
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spsPerson]
    @PersonID INT OUTPUT,
    @Firstname VARCHAR(50),
    @Lastname VARCHAR(255)
AS
    INSERT INTO PersonTable (Firstname,  Lastname)
    VALUES (@Firstname,  @Lastname)

    SET  @PersonID  = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
GO
```

I don't care about output param, just want to execute this stored procedure without changing it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is for the OUTPUT parameter, you are assigning a value of 0 to it, which is causing the problem.

This is how you would execute it in TSQL to get results to a variable `@results`:

```
declare @results int;
exec dbo.spsPerson @results OUTPUT, @Firstname=N'test', @Lastname=N'test'
select @results;
```

If you don't care about the results at all:

```
exec dbo.spsPerson NULL, @Firstname=N'test', @Lastname=N'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't test it at moment. Do you try it and let me know

**Define store function:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spsPerson]
    @Firstname VARCHAR(50),
    @Lastname VARCHAR(255)
AS
    INSERT INTO PersonTable (Firstname,  Lastname)
    VALUES (@Firstname,  @Lastname)

    return (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('PersonTable'))
GO
```

**Query in sequelize:**

```
sequelize
          .query('CALL spsPerson (:Firstname, :Lastname)', 
                {replacements: { Firstname: 'fistname', Lastname: 'lastname' }})
          .then(v=>console.log(v));
```